# Python return combinations of a list of ranges?

Tags: python, list, permutation

I'm working on returning all the combinations of a list based on a list of ranges.

So if I have:

```
test_list = [range(0,11,1),range(0,11,2),range(0,11,5)]
```

And I want to return a list with all the possible combinations based on the ranges.
For Example:

```
output_list[[0,0,5],[0,0,10],[0,2,0],[0,4,0],[0,6,0].......]
```

But all I have been able to do is:

```
import itertools

test_list = [range(0,11,1),range(0,11,2),range(0,11,5)]
output_list = []
for i in itertools.permutations(test_list):
    if i not in output_list:
        output_list.append(i)
```

Which returns each range permuted,(a list of ranges again)?

Comment: Try product in itertools module - http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
output_list = list(itertools.product(*test_list))
```

Comment: Hey dave, thanks for the help!  Now one thing I'm not sure about is the '*' on the line?  Is this to denote that it is an argument?

Comment: Yes it unpacks the list as arguments to `itertools.product`

Comment: @tijko: the `*` splat operator is used to unpack `test_list` as a set of arguments.

Comment: That's for [tuple/list unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments). Basically, it turns `func([a,b,c])` into `func(a, b, c)`. Essentially `*[a,b,c]` is the same as `a, b, c`

Comment: [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) is the name for what [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does. "Cartesian" means unable to google it because you don't know what it's called.